# Phrase for inventory movement

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase that describes the in-and-outs (purchase and sale) of inventory items, kind of like an account statement for bank accounts.

Some phrases that I thought about are 'inventory movement', 'inventory statement', or 'unit movement', I'm not sure if there's a specific term.

I'm looking for a phrase to be applied in a business application

Comment: What phrases have you already found and why were they not appropriate for your needs?

Comment: I'm guessing iceman2992 is you as well, Michel? Just saw the edit request.

Comment: What's wrong with your own term, *inventory movement*?

Comment: @Lawrence It appears that OP has tried to edit that into the question under another username, which was rejected by one of the reviewers because it looked like someone else responding to the question by way of an edit.

Comment: Why different accounts?

Comment: Sounds like you are describing an inventory register.

Comment: Inventory is said to be logged, and the software is called inventory logging software. Product items are entered/removed from inventory. Also, in accounting, one says: recorded in inventory/removed from inventory.

Comment: movement in a bank account is credit/debits to an account. In inventory,items recorded/items removed.

Comment: What are the in/out activities you're trying to describe? Are they transfers between warehouses of the same business, or purchase-and-sale of goods?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it exactly meets your need, by maybe [turnover](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turnover) is a useful term for you.  You could call it a **"turnover statement"**.

> turnover: the rate at which the goods in a store are sold and replaced by other goods

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of a specific term for what you describe (though @James' "turnover" is close).  Supposing that retail sales is the primary business of the organization to which the document pertains, however, you might simply call it an "**activity statement**".